# How to print the last string from socket

Tags: php, string, sockets

I'm trying to print the last string from server respone. I'm write the following:

```
$fp = fsockopen("smtp.mail.ru", 25);
// There is fputs functions
echo fgets($fp);// This is print the first string
```

But I want to print the last string of the server's response. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the strings into array of stings, then print the last string:

```
<?php
$cntr = 0;
$strarray = [];
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) 
{
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} 
else 
{
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);

    while (!feof($fp)) 
    {
        $strarray[$cntr] = fgets($fp);
        $cntr = $cntr + 1;
    }

    fclose($fp);
}

//Now, print the last string in the array:
echo end($strarray);

?>
```